# Mongo DB - $inc allowed for numbers only

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to create my first Meteor App and I'm stuck on what should be a simple process. Here are the inserts that I used to first set up the DB;

```
income.insert({income_acct_name:  "Account 1", income_acct_budget: 0, income_acct_total: 0});
income.insert({income_acct_name:  "Account 2", income_acct_budget: 0, income_acct_total: 0});
income.insert({income_acct_name:  "Account 3", income_acct_budget: 0, income_acct_total: 0});
```

here is template;

```
<template name="income">
  {{#each accounts}}
    <tr>
      <td class="row1"><input type="text" value="{{income_acct_name}}"></td>
      <td class="row2"><input type="text" value="{{income_acct_budget}}"></td>
      <td class="row3">0%</td>
      <td class="row4"><input type="text" value="0" id="income_amt_entered"></td>
      <td class="row5">$ </td>
      <td class="row6"> - </td>
      <td class="row7"></td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

and this is the helper that throws the error;

```
Template.income.events ({
        'change td.row4': function(theEvent, theTemplate) {
            var rowId = this._id;
            Session.set('changedRow', rowId);
            var changedRow = Session.get('changedRow');
            var amount = theTemplate.find('#income_amt_entered').value;
            income.update (
                {"_id": changedRow},
                {$inc: {"income_acct_total": amount}}
            )
            //console.log(amount);
        }
});
```

So in my form I enter an amount like 45.50 in row4 to update "income_acct_total" and I get that error. I'm using pretty much the same code from the Leader Board app that is working. The amount entered appears correctly in the console log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get number from '#income_amt_entered' input  :

```
var amount = parseFloat(theTemplate.find('#income_amt_entered').value);
```

Comment: That did it. I was hoping to save input validation to later in the App to keep it simple at first. Guess I can't do that. Much thanks!

Comment: $inc expects Number not String. That's the reason.